Deprecating Facebook Groups API - Alternative way?
Recently facebook made some changes to their api and depricated the "Groups API".
We used it to add weekly a post to our group in an automated way. This ofc stopped working.
Now i have tried to read up on some documentation but was not able to even do a call towards a group.
Some information we found:
Blogpost facebook v19
& Discussion on facebook community

Ps it works for pages. But i cant transform my group to a page because it needs to be private.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thx

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
